# How do I delete an item in rails without actually removing it from the website (like deleting a product from a wishlist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a delete button that will allow users to delete a movie in a list they have created, but not actually being able to delete the movie from the website.

this is what I have in my lists show page

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @list, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

obviously @list destroys the whole list and I don't want that. I want them to have the option to delete an entire list, but I also want them to have the option to just delete an item in the list as well.

in my list controller I only have

```
def destroy
 @list.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
format.html { redirect_to lists_url, notice: 'List was successfully destroyed.' }
format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

and in my movie controller I have the same thing except

```
@movie.destroy
```

I tried

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @list[:movie_id], method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

but that only gave me a route error since I was calling the actual movie id and I just want the id of the list item.

in my routes.db I have this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users
 resources :lists 
 resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
 resources :movies, except: [:index] do
  member do
  put "like", to: "movies#upvote"
  put "dislike", to: "movies#downvote"
 end
end
 get "discover", to: "movies#index"
 get "movies", to: "movies#films"
get "tv_shows", to: "movies#tv_shows"
resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]

 devise_scope :user do
 authenticated :user do
  root 'movies#films', as: :authenticated_root
  end
 end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a third model to associate between movies and lists, since this is a many-to-many relationship. Here are how the model relationships might look:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_movies
  has_many :movies, through: :list_movies
end

class ListMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :movie
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_movies
  has_many :lists, through: :list_movies
end
```

And the migration to add the join table between lists and movies:

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change     
    create_table :list_movies do |t|
      t.belongs_to :lists, index: true
      t.belongs_to :movies, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

With the structure properly established, you will be able to add and delete movie's from a user's list, because they are referenced as list_movies. A list_movie simply associates a particular movie to a particular list. Only the list_movie records will actually be added or deleted when making changes to the list, not an actual movie record.

If you want to remove an actual movie, and you want all instances of that movie in user's lists to also be removed, you may want to add dependent destroy to the model, i.e. , "dependent: :destroy" and same for lists:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies, through: :list_movies, dependent: :destroy
end 
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists, through: :list_movies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then add the appropriate routes.

Finally, in your view you will be able to do something like this:

```
<% @list.movies.each do |movie| %>
  <h3><%= movie.title %></h3>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', movie, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

More information about associations in Rails is available here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I made all the necessary changes, but I m stuck at in my views folder because I already have an each loop doing something else and I don't know how to add another my each loop looks like this
<% @list.user.find_up_voted_items.each do |movie| %>

Comment: The list belongs to the user, correct? If so, the List model should "belongs_to :user". Then you could have @list.up_voted_items.

You may need to modify your method definition for "up_voted_items" on the model in order to do what you want. I'm assuming it is just returning up-voted items on the current list, which would be list_movies now. You may also need to add a column to list_movies for vote tally.